# One Page Nav JS > highlighted link + scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery-One-Page-Nav (and Bootstrap) and I have 2 problems :

- The active link is displayed when I scroll the page but not when I click on a link
- The position when I click on a link is not at the top of the section (I guess it lacks the height of the navbar)

The whole site is here : http://www.mrsmith.be/

Stylesheet : http://www.mrsmith.be/css/style.css

The js I use :

```
$('.nav').onePageNav({
    currentClass: 'current',
    changeHash: false,
    scrollSpeed: 750,
    scrollThreshold: 0.5,
    filter: '',
    easing: 'swing',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The active link is displayed when I scroll the page but not when I
>   click on a link

It's because you have to override the bootstrap css.
When you click on a link, here is the bootstrap css for pseudo :focus class

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

So, it stay grey and not red. You can click on the body and it become red....

After :
The fact to use `scrollThreshold: 0.5` make the link become active when the target comes to 50% of the screen height...

Comment: Great, thanks for you anwser ! The part whith focus: thing is ok ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Put12co22mer2, indeed it looks ok but actually if you scroll a bit upwards, is lacks some height, like the top of the sections...